# How can I show that this improper integral does not converge?

Tags: integration

I'm interested in proving that this integral does not converge.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^3 + 4x} \, dx$$
Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Well it does converge, because you are continuous at the origin and decay sufficiently fast for large $x$. There is no issue

Comment: I see that the integrals over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ both converge.  That's very unfortunate actually... back to the drawing board.

Comment: It converges to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2cpaU.png) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, there is no problem for large $x$.

Close to $x=0$, use Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$, square it and perform long division. You should end with $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^3 + 4x}=\frac{x}{4}-\frac{7 x^3}{48}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, no problem.

You could even do it simpler writing, for small $x$, $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^3 + 4x}=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^2\frac{x^2}{x^3 + 4x}\approx\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^2\frac{x}{ 4}\approx \frac{x}{ 4}$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $sin ^2 x= {1- cos 2x \over2}$. Now in the interval $[1,+\infty[ $, the integral of $1\over 4 x+x^3$ diverges. But with one integration by part, you can prove that, on the same interval $[1,+\infty[$ the (oscillatory) integral of ${cos 2x\over x+x^3}$ converges. So your integral diverges at infinity.